# Azure Mobile Services Custom LoginProvider redirect issues in Universal App with AuthenticationHandler

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, azure-mobile-services, win-universal-app, owin-middleware

**The Problem:**

MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync never exits the login dialog - even after the access token gets returned.

**The Environment:**

- **Backend:** Windows Azure Mobile Service .Net/C#
- **Frontend:** Windows 8.1 Universal Store App. .Net/C#

**The Details:**

In my app, the following code fails to return from the dialog that is brought up on the second line:

```
var client = new MobileServiceClient("https://hana.azure-mobile.net", applicationKey);
var result = await client.LoginAsync("SmartThings");
```

**Speculation:**

I suspect that the code in my custom AuthenticationHandler for handling a challenge, is mostly to blame.  The RedirectUri in the AuthenticationProperties for my override of ApplyResponseChallengeAsync, is always null - so it sets the redirect uri to the request uri.

The code looks like the following:

```
        var redirectUri = Request.FromPath(Options.CallbackPath);
        var properties = challenge.Properties;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(properties.RedirectUri))
        {
            properties.RedirectUri = Request.Uri.AbsoluteUri;
        }

        // OAuth2 10.12 CSRF
        GenerateCorrelationId(properties);

        var requestUrl = FormAuthorizeRequest(properties, redirectUri);
        Response.Redirect(requestUrl);
```

**Attempts at resolution**

1. Use WebAuthenticationBroker instead of MobileServiceClient and expliticly provide the callback uri.
2. Remove reassignment to redirect uri.
3. Switch redirect and request uris.
4. Throw salt over my shoulder.
5. Use Test frontend on service to navigate and test login.
6. Use HttpClient and explicitly construct the request with the following parameter keys: "redirect_uri", "redirect_url", "redirectUrl", "redirectUri".
7. Bleed a goat
8. Change the CallbackPath value of the AuthenticationOptions to "/signin-SmartThings".
9. Await Ragnarok

**Additional Details**

I had to create a custom LoginProvider and OWIN Middleware to register my custom AuthenticationHandler into the owin pipeline.  This appears to have been setup correctly, but the implementation of my AuthenticationHandler may be erroneous.  I will gladly provide additional details on request if it will help expedite this issue.

**Updates:**

The response from SmartThings gives an error with "redirect_mismatch" in the body when trying to login from a WebAuthenticationBroker with a provided callback uri.

However, when navigating through the browser, the redirect uri gets processed as "https://hana.azure-mobile.net/signin-SmartThings?code=somemassivecode"

This confuses me a bit because I was expecting to see an access token, rather than an auth token, as the redirect uri.

Comment: Is the problem on the phone side, or Windows store side or both?

Comment: I am not using a windows phone project yet.  Right now, I'm only using a Universal Windows Store App for Windows 8.1.  I suspect that it is more of an issue with the Azure Mobile Service than the WebAuthenticationBroker.  But that's purely speculation.

Comment: IS there anything in the output window of the debugger?   Not sure the "SmartThings" provider is known to Mobile Services.  Tough to say without knowing what that is.

Comment: I created a custom LoginProvider/Middleware for "SmartThings".  The code for the potentially erroneous Owin Middleware was posted in my question.  But, if you would like any other code from the pipeline, I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: Also, just so you are aware, the endpoint is publicly accessible and you are able to actually authenticate and authorize the identity by navigating through the endpoint.  The issue appears to be that the redirect url on the return context is malformed - meaning that the WebAuthenticationBroker doesn't know how to respond to the redirect.

Comment: Have you tried this API for the callback URI:
WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri();

Comment: Yes, I used the override of WebAuthenticationBroker that takes in a Callback, and provided the value you mentioned.